# I am trying to extract only the identifiers, arithemetic and relational operators from my C code and here

Tags: lex

I am trying to extract only the identifiers, arithmetic and relational operators from my C code and here is my lex code :

```
%{
  #include "y.tab.h"
  #include "Expression.h"
%}

%%

"=="            {return EQ;}
"<"             {return '<';}
">"             {return '>';}
"="             {return '=';}
"+"             {return '+';}
"-"             {return '-';}
"*"             {return '*';}
"/"             {return '/';}
","             {return ',';}
";"             {return ';';}
"("             {return '(';}
")"             {return ')';}
"{"             {return '{';}
"}"             {return '}';}
"["             {return '[';}
"]"             {return ']';}
"int"               {return INT;} 
"char"              {return CHAR;}
"float"             {return FLOAT;}
"long"              {return LONG;}
"double"            {return DOUBLE;}
"return"            {return RETURN;}
"if"                {return IF;}
"else"              {return ELSE;}


[0-9]+              {return Number;}
[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*        {return Identifier;}                }

[ \t]               ;
[\n]                ;
"."             {return BADTOKEN;}


%%
```

But I keep encountering the error, tinyc.l:45: EOF encountered inside an action. Anyway to sort this?

Comment: where is the line 45?

Comment: Well my entire code including a blank line in the end is of 44 lines.If I remove the blank lines my code is of 43 lines and then it shows the error as tinyc.l:44:EOF .......

Comment: My eventual motive is to extract the identifiers along with their associated arithmetic/relational operations so that I can send such tokens to my parser.

Comment: `"." {return BADTOKEN;}` returns BADTOKEN when it sees a literal `.`. That's what double quotes do in flex: treat the contents as ordinary characters rather than metacharacters. If you want to match "any character other than newline", you need an unquoted `.`. To catch this type of error, use `%option nodefault`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*        {return Identifier;}                }
```

this line looks at least suspicious. Looks like additional ending bracket `}`?